# What do the numbers by "Global Unlock" mean?

Tags: nuclear-dawn

In my "Career" menu, I have some confusing numbers.

[image]

What's the "166"?  I thought that was my experience, but my experience is -414, as denoted by the sad face.

Is it all the experience I've gained, ignoring the experience I've lost?  Or is it something else?  What's that number?

<sub>Curiously, after another game, my experience went up, and that 166 went *down*.</sub>